# How can an entry type have its own search and categories?

Tags: categories, entry-type, search

I have an entry type whose content will be separated from the main content. So I was wondering how can we give an entry type its own search and categories? Possible?

Answer (score 3):

Sure it's possible. There's the [`type()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#type) parameter available for ElementCriteriaModels to filter the returned results by only those entry types you need.

To separate the categories, I'd set up multiple [category groups](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories#category-groups), one for each of your entry types.

For example:

```
{% set categoryParams = {
    group: 'audioCategories',
    slug: 'podcasts'
} %}

{% set category = craft.categories(categoryParams).first() %}
{% set searchTerm = 'basketball OR soccer' %}

{% set entryParams = {
    section: 'news',
    type: 'audio',
    relatedTo: category,
    search: searchTerm
} %}

{% for entry in craft.entries(entryParams) %}
    <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This would list only those entries which are

1. in a **section** named "news"
2. given an **entry type** (and entry template) "audio"
3. related to a category from the **category group** "audioCategories" (I additionally filter for just the one cat. named "podcasts" to keep the example a little simpler)
4. matching to the **search term** "basketball OR soccer"